Database entries with start date and end date within a period
I'm trying to create several database entries with a start date and an end date.
The whole thing should always be created in a 7-day period. For example: start date: June 6th, 2024; end date: June 18th, 2024. In this case, database entries should be created for June 6th, June 12th and June 18th. Within the foreach loop, up to 8 entries should be made for each individual date (hour 1 - 8). The whole thing becomes a calendar. Someone enters an appointment, this appointment can go from the first hour to the 8th hour. And this appointment should be entered weekly (every 7 days) up to an end date. Unfortunately, I can't see the forest for the trees at the moment. This is what my code looks like:
$startDateTime = new DateTime();
$endDateTime = new DateTime();
$dateInterval = new DateInterval( 'P7D' );
$datePeriod = new DatePeriod($startDateTime->setTimestamp($fromform->date), $dateInterval, $endDateTime->setTimestamp($fromform->reservto));

foreach ( $datePeriod as $dateTime ) {
    //Here the individual hours (1-8) are counted up.
    for ( $i = $fromform->time; $i = $fromform->timeto; $i++ ) {
        //I want to save this format in the database.
        $newdate = $dateTime->format("Y-m-d");

        $recordtoinsert = new stdClass();
        $recordtoinsert->datum = $newdate;
        $recordtoinsert->ustd = $i;
        $recordtoinsert->resfuer = $fromform->resfuer;

        if ( $fromform->room == 1 ) {
            $buchungfromform = 'Raum: ' . $fromform->raum . ' durch ' . $fromform->resfuer;
            $bgcolor = 'blue';
        } elseif ( $fromform->laptopcheck == 1 ) {
            $buchungfromform = 'Laptop: ' . $fromform->laptop . '(' . $fromform->timelaptopanzahl . ' Stk.)' . ' durch ' . $fromform->resfuer;
            $bgcolor = 'green';
        }
        $recordtoinsert->buchung = $buchungfromform;
        $recordtoinsert->userid = $fromform->userid;
        $recordtoinsert->bgcolor = $bgcolor;

        $DB->insert_record( 'bs_steinweg', $recordtoinsert );
        //Zurück zur Lernbüroseite

    }
    $getsaved = get_string( 'saved', 'local_buchungssystem' );
        redirect( $CFG->wwwroot . '/local/buchungssystem/bs_sw.php', $getsaved );
}

When I make the database entries, it creates tens of thousands of entries in a continuous loop.

Typo in$i = $fromform->timeto: = should be <=. You're assigning, not comparing, and it will always be truthy, so you have an infinite loop.

Ok, the infinite loops are gone. However, it only makes one entry for me. Not 3 entries for 3 different dates.

Use var_dump() to make sure all the variables contain what you expect. Put var_dump($datePeriod); before the loop, and var_dump($dateTime); inside it.

If I enter the start date 07.06 and the end date 21.06, then I expect 3 entries from the foreach loop. It only gives me one entry.

Your question is very clear about what you expect. I'm trying to tell you how to debug it.

Do you have code that parses 07.06 into a timestamp value?

I get the timestamp via my form. I just tested it and it gives me the following number: 1717624800.

Then I think it should work. Have you performed the debugging I described?

Yes, as I wrote in my second to last answer, I only get one value in the foreach. So var_dump($dateTime); should output 3 entries but only outputs one entry.

And what about var_dump($datePeriod)? Does it show the expected start and end dates?

What does the redirect() function do? I suspect it's exiting the script, so the loop stops. Those two lines should probably be after the loop.

No, also just one value.

Then I guess there's a problem with $fromform->reservto

This is basic debugging technique. Print all the variables that could possibly have an effect on the result, and make sure they all contain what you expect.

I'm so stupid. The redirect was the problem. I'm very embarrassed now.
